# UI-Router Resolve In Infinite Loop On Promise Failure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to redirect users based on authentication so within the resolve of each route state I've placed my service for checking for authentication so in this case login and dashboard.

```
    .state('login', {
        url: "/login",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: '/app/login/login.html'
    })

        // Default login state
        .state('login.index', { 
            url: "",
            templateUrl: "/app/login/views/login.html",
            controller: 'LoginController',
            controllerAs: 'loginCtrl',
            resolve: {
                UserAuth: session
            }
        })

    .state('dashboard', {
        url: "/dashboard",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: '/app/dashboard/dashboard.html',
        resolve: {
            UserAuth: session
        }
    })

        // Default dashboard state
        .state('dashboard.index', {
            url: "",
            templateUrl: '/app/dashboard/views/page1.html',
            controller: 'Page1Controller',
            controllerAs: 'page1Ctrl',
            resolve: {
                UserAuth: session
            }
        })

        // with multiple states like the child route above...
```

Within my .config for routing I also set up session for use above, which on promise success or existence of a session $state.go to dashboard, else on promise failure $state.go to login.

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    var session = ['$q', '$location', '$state', 'SessionService', 
        function( $q, $location, $state, SessionService ) {
            return SessionService.session()

                .then(function( session ) {

                    // Check location path as $state is not resolved yet
                    var location = $location.path();

                    /**
                     * Check user authentication to dashboard and handle
                     * state change if session already exists
                     */
                    if( location.indexOf('login') === 1 ) {
                        // Redirect to default dashboard view
                        $state.go('dashboard.index');
                    }

                }, function( error ) {

                    // Check location path as $state is not resolved yet
                    var location = $location.path();

                    /**
                     * Check for unauthorized access to dashboard and handle
                     * state change if not located on login view
                     */
                    if( location.indexOf( 'dashboard' ) === 1 ) {
                        // Redirect to default login view
                        $state.go('login.index');
                    }

                    // Don't propagate error since it has been handled and it prevents page
                    // return $q.reject( error );
                });
        }];
```

But, it's running through an infinite loop of 403 errors when I let the session time out, which is the correct server response for promise failure.  It enters the if statement, and runs $state.go('login.index'), but keeps looping and never replaces the state with login.  Can anyone see what I've done wrong?  Works in all cases except session time out, then doesn't redirect.

Comment: Well i can imagine what's going wrong, the login.index route resolves whatever your SessionService returns, it returns success as your backend login route might not be authenticated, it redirects to dashboard.index, authentication fails, redirect to login.index,  rinse & repeat. Just a guess, but that could be what's going on..

Comment: Yah, I've changed $state.go to $location.path('/login') with $location.replace(); and it seems to correct it.  I thought not returning the $q.reject would signal the error had been handled and would allow for the route to resolve, but noticed it wouldn't make it there with $state.go before the return.  Thanks for being a sounding board.

Comment: Glad I could help! Many people use HTTP Interceptors for things like that, in case you were interested. Might have some sample code hanging around somewhere too ;-)

Comment: Thanks, if you have time I'd definitely be interested in seeing how you handle this using HTTP Interceptors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dropped together some code that I used in a past project that displays how I setup Authentication and interception of 401/403 on Angular side of things.

https://gist.github.com/jfornoff/4637069c398dc2f5b881

Note that especially the authorization of users can not be reliably done in the frontend and always have your backend authenticate and not give out data blindly to some end-point that your frontend should be using ;-) But I guess that's pretty self-explanatory.

Hope I could help you out!
Bye,
Jan